# How to configure Apache to work as proxy (load balancer) for j2ee server?

Tags: apache, jakarta-ee, mod-proxy

I have apache web server installed as frontend and I have j2ee SAP Netweaver Application Server installed in Intranet server. How can I configure apache to forward requests and response to/from j2ee app server.
for example, external apache server's ip is 9.20.1.1:80. 
internal sap server's address is 192.168.0.1/sap/bc/gui/sap/its/webgui?sap_client=200
I want access to my sap app server for example 9.20.1.1/sapserver/sap/bc/gui/sap/its/webgui?sap_client=200

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mentioned load balancing- so presumably you want to be able to add more Application Servers that are served through a single address.  I hope they are stateless or storing session information in a database. You can use Apache to serve as a reverse proxy load balancer with `mod_proxy_balancer`. Docs are [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy_balancer.html).

Here's an example of what to add to your httpd.conf from [this link](http://blog.innerewut.de/2006/4/21/scaling-rails-with-apache-2-2-mod_proxy_balancer-and-mongrel).

```
 <Proxy balancer://myclustername>
  # cluster member 1
  BalancerMember http://192.168.0.1:3000 
  BalancerMember http://192.168.0.1:3001

  # cluster member 2, the fastest machine so double the load
  BalancerMember http://192.168.0.11:3000 loadfactor=2
  BalancerMember http://192.168.0.11:3001 loadfactor=2

  # cluster member 3
  BalancerMember http://192.168.0.12:3000
  BalancerMember http://192.168.0.12:3001

  # cluster member 4
  BalancerMember http://192.168.0.13:3000
  BalancerMember http://192.168.0.13:3001
</Proxy>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin info@meinprof.de
  ServerName www.meinprof.de
  ServerAlias meinprof.de
  ProxyPass / balancer://meinprofcluster/
  ProxyPassReverse / balancer://meinprofcluster/
  ErrorLog /var/log/www/www.meinprof.de/apache_error_log
  CustomLog /var/log/www/www.meinprof.de/apache_access_log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is often mistakenly referred to as a reverse proxy. If you use a search engine to find "reverse proxy apache" you will get many good results.

The quick answer is to add something like this to your apache.conf

> ProxyPass /sap/ 192.168.0.1/sap/
>
> < Location /sap/ >
>
> ```
>     ProxyPassReverse /sap/
> ```
>
> < /Location >

See also the modrewrite rools and the [P] option.

Comment: Actually, this is a reverse proxy. A forward proxy is a host that channels requests to provide caching and filtering. I don't know why you would say it is "mistakenly" referred to as a reverse proxy.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have mod_proxy enabled, add to you're sites-available:

```
   ProxyRequests Off
   <Location "/sapserver">
        ProxyPass http://192.168.0.1
        ProxyPassReverse http://192.168.0.1
   </Location>
```

Be careful though as this does expose your internal site to the entire internet.

Comment: Doesn't work pretty good. I've experienced issues with image rendering and styles of page (j2ee application). Page rendered without graphics and css styles. What I can you advise?

Comment: Can you check that the J2EE app isn't referencing the images and CSS via absolute URLs instead of relative?